# Electron forge, make command: override default values

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-forge

It's actually my first time developing an Electron app.
I have used the cli make command to package the app for the actual machine I am working on and everything works fine. However when I decided to pass options for the arch and the platform types through the make command, it seems that still builds with the default values (Those of the machine I am developing on).

> npm run make --platform=win32 --arch=ia32

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for the answer. The -- are required for npm run before passing any arguments. Therefore, the correct command would be like that:

> npm run make -- --platform=win32 --arch=ia32